# Selenium find_element_by_xpath last

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a bunch of elements and need to select last one using xpath.
The elements looks like:

```
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Actions')])[2]
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Actions')])[3]
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Actions')])[4]
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Actions')])[5]
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Actions')])[6]
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Actions')])[7]
```

http://prntscr.com/cc3gxd

Using Selenium IDE, I see, that I can select last element, by using:

```
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'Actions')])[last ()]
```

But Selenium Webdriver does not understand this syntax (error NoSuchElementException)

It only understands this syntax:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Actions')][last ()]").click()
```

But in this case I will select first element.

Please help me to rewrite xpath to select last element instead of first in Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: Did you try just `driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Actions')])[last ()]").click()`

Comment: It gives error in shell:
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector (//a[contains(text(),'Actions'‌​)])[last ()] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression (//a[contains(text(),'Actions'‌​)])[last ()] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: last() will get you the last child and not the last element for a locator. If your link tags all had the same parent then it would work. In your case you need to find some unique identifier for the link you want. Or else use find_elements and use the last one in the returned list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is selecting first because you are using find element by xpath try

```
ele=  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Actions')][last ()]")
ele[-1].click
```

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath()` would return you a list of `WebElement`s, there is no `click()` method for the list, it would fail.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The `click` is a method and should be called.

Comment: I find `[last()] ` is not working, with or without this will both return all elements